# CSS: Mostrar glyphicon justo debajo de otro glyphicon

Tags: html, css

Tengo esta vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que las flechas se vieran las dos a la derecha del nombre de la columna, **una encima de la otra**.

Que estilo css debería aplicar a la clase .glyphicon-arrow-up y .glyphicon-arrow-down?

```css
.glyphicon-arrow-up{
font-size:12px;
position:absolute;
margin-top:6px;
}
.glyphicon-arrow-down{
font-size:12px;
position:absolute;
margin-top:19px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="columnidclient thcenter">ID<a href="{{route('admin.clients.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByAsc"></span></a><a href="{{route('admin.clients.order',['field' => 'id','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByIdDesc"></span></a></th>
            <th>Nombre<a href="{{route('admin.clients.order', ['field' => 'name','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByAsc"></span></a><a href="{{route('admin.clients.order',['field' => 'name','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByNameDesc"></span></a></th>
            <th>Slug<a href="{{route('admin.clients.order', ['field' => 'slug','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByAsc"></span></a><a href="{{route('admin.clients.order',['field' => 'slug','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderBySlugDesc"></span></a></th>
            <th class="thcenter">Prioridad<a href="{{route('admin.clients.order', ['field' => 'priority','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByAsc"></span></a><a href="{{route('admin.clients.order',['field' => 'priority','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByPriorityDesc"></span></a></th>
            <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Acciones</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Vale, aclarado el ejemplo.. ¿Has probado algo para que queden una encima de otra? Por qué no te funcionó? Un saludo

Comment: Me gustaría hacerlo de manera que quede 'fijo' uno encima de otro. Solo se me ocurre hacerlo a ojo con margins, si sabes de alguna manera dímela y investigo únicamente eso.

Comment: La verdad que no entiendo algo, el codigo que acabo de poner a mi me funciona bien con position: absolute; y margin-top, en cambio en el código snipped no funciona. Voy a chequear todos los estilos aplicados a la clase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los estilos de bootstrap te estaban sobreescribiendo el `position` porque la clase `.glyphicon` tiene un `position:relative`. Añadiendo la clase `.glyphicon` a las tuyas les damos más especificidad y cogerá tus estilos.

También añado `position: relative` al `th` para que lo use como referencia.

```css
th {
  position: relative;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-up {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-down {
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="columnidclient thcenter">ID
        <a href="{{route('admin.clients.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByAsc"></span></a>
        <a href="{{route('admin.clients.order',['field' => 'id','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByIdDesc"></span></a></th>
      <th>Nombre<a href="{{route('admin.clients.order', ['field' => 'name','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByAsc"></span></a><a href="{{route('admin.clients.order',['field' => 'name','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByNameDesc"></span></a></th>
      <th>Slug<a href="{{route('admin.clients.order', ['field' => 'slug','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByAsc"></span></a><a href="{{route('admin.clients.order',['field' => 'slug','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderBySlugDesc"></span></a></th>
      <th class="thcenter">Prioridad<a href="{{route('admin.clients.order', ['field' => 'priority','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByAsc"></span></a>
        <a href="{{route('admin.clients.order',['field' => 'priority','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByPriorityDesc"></span></a>
      </th>
      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```